# Что значит Order Allow,Deny в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Что значит Order Allow,Deny в .htaccess?

Закрывает доступ к папки и всем директориям

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
```

Зачем нужна первая строка `Order Allow,Deny` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка «Order Allow,Deny» определяет, в какой последовательности выполняются запрещающие (deny) и разрешающие (allow) условия на предоставления доступа